How many actions can you take in a turn?
How many actions can you take in a turn?
The "combat actions" on p.10 mentions "a few actions", but that a nebulous number 
Appreciate it's meant to be a light rules set, but this question is always going to be asked by the players

It seems there can be only one attack per turn
I think WRM did a poor job explaining the action economy. The rules just say this:

Combat turns are generally short, a few seconds in duration, so characters can only perform a few actions. Running a short distance, drawing a weapon, attacking a foe, and casting a spell are reasonable actions that can be performed during one turn.

What can we deduce from this text:

"a few actions" suggests that there may be several of them
you can move, attack a foe, and cast a spell in one turn (and this is just an example)
turns is measured in seconds, not actions, although this measurement is not precise ("a few seconds")

So several short actions can be performed in one turn, while long ones may last several turns. The last word is for the game master, as usual. From my experience, this works fine — the GM is one who facilitate the move order, so you just go to the next player when you feel it's his/her time to act.
However, the other piece of the rules assumes there can be only one attack:

If the GM approves, PCs using two weapons may also attack with both weapons in one round if they take the talent Double Attack, which has Dual
Wielding as a prerequisite.

So there's an optional Talent which is called "Double Attack". Without it, a PC can't perform a double attack per one turn. This "one attack per turn" rule seems very reasonable from the perspective of the combat dynamics. So my guess is:
You can do multiple actions per turn, but only one attack per turn (including magical ones).

Maybe "characters can only perform a few actions" may also mean that the actions that you can do is limited - not that you can do several actions. I'm not sure. That sentence can mean both things.

AFAIK, "a few" (with an article) means there are options. Although I'd prefer a confirmation from those whose English level is higher than mine

It can mean both things. Still, I do agree with your argument. The limited actions it gives as examples suggests that it would be one attack.

English is my native language, and "a few" is more than "a couple", but less than "a lot" ... which isn't very helpful  :-(
And seems the Double Attack talent isn't in the talent table

@SteveC I think it is not in the table just because it is optional.
